# Entering and viewing Cyrillic strings in R

Tags: r, string, encoding

How to handle Cyrillic strings in R?

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Polish")

dataset <- data.frame( ProductName = c('ąęćśżźół','тест') )

#Encoding(dataset) <- "UTF-8" #this line does not change anything

View(dataset)
```

The code above results in:
[image]

But I would like to get what I typed in `тест` instead of sequence `<U+number>`. Is there any way for that?

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691555/cyrillic-encoding-output-in-r) despite my `Sys.setlocale()` is not `"ru_RU"` and your code works fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and see the cyrillic test in my data frame.
I think you should check what your locale is (with `sessionInfo`) and whether it supports UTF.

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357425/displaying-cyrillic-in-rstudio-console) and try to maybe change the encoding of your column.

```
Encoding(dataset$Cyrillic) <- "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing encoding is useless. Changing locale to Russian helps only in case of Russian names. But it messes string values of other non Roman letters. I have edited my question to better reflect my situation. Nevertheless I can always split it into parts and use different locale for each part. It is a pity it cannot be done easily. SQL Server for example can handle whatever diacritic barbarian marks in its nvarchar variable.